# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar usando las ListasSencillas?

Tags: java, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo una lista de canciones y necesito filtrar por precio pero no se muy bien como se podría hacer eso. Tengo el siguiente método pero no se como completarlo.

```
public static ListaSencilla<Cancion> filtraPrecio(ListaSencilla<Cancion> can, double precio){

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para filtrar en una lista, recórrela y borra los elementos que no cumplan la condición. Suponiendo que quieres eliminar las canciones con costo superior a precio:

```
Iterator<Cancion> it = can.iterator();
while( it.hasNext() ) {
  Cancion cancion = it.next();
  if( cancion.getPrecio() > precio ){
    it.remove();  
  } 
}
```

Además se puede hacer de esta otra forma. Aquí estamos obteniendo las canciones con precio inferior o igual al precio pasado al método:

```
can.stream().filter(cancion -> cancion.getPrecio() <= precio).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Perfecto !!! muchisimas Gracias !!!!

Comment: Hola @Enoy  te sugerimos responder a preguntas que sean realizadas de acuerdo a lo dictado en el [help], de otra forma la pregunta solo será útil para el que pregunta y no para la comunidad y de esta forma obtendrías reputación para tus contribuciones, saludos.